# I can't find the "Add experience" button in the "Developer Story"

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

I want add the job position I'm currently working, but I can't find the "add experience" button *(or equivalent)* - I can edit the current data available in my Developer Story.

This is a little embarrassing, but, can anyone guide me where is the "add experience" button in the Developer Story?

Also, maybe for guidance for others: is there a manual for use the "Developer Story"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Developer Story there’s a set of buttons to add different entries to your timeline. Sounds like you need a ‘Position’ entry:

[image: Developer Story Items]